# Merging folders or subfolders with same name using C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have two folders at different locations but with the same name. A file is generated in one of the folders and it is to be copied to the other folder but without overwriting the existing contents in C#.

`File.Copy` overwrites the contents which makes me lose the previous contents. Is it possible to merge the contents in the folder?

Comment: Question:  What is the "rule" if the same file already exists in the mirror directory?  Do you not copy it, or do you append something like "_1" to the end of the root file name.  If you define the proper response to this condition, I believe you'll have your answer.

Comment: sounds like you really want rsync http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded version of `File.Copy`:

`File.Copy(sourcefile,destfile,false);`